# GIT stage and commit only files with a certain file ending

Tags: git-commit, git, git-stage

I have tons of modified files, and a good 2/3s of the files are images that I don't care much about, but I still want to commit them.
For the rest I need to really look hard at the changes. To minimize the files I need to look at I want to only stage .png and .jpg and .gif files and commit them (cutting down the background noise in order to look at the beef).

Having said that...

*How would you stage and commit only files with these file endings without adding each file separately?*

Edit:

**Files are modified**

**Directory structure is not flat**

I am overwriting a WP Theme that I have highly customized and there is a security update I need to apply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply

```
git add \*.jpg \*.png
```

This will add all tracked and modified files in your repository which match the wildcard pattern

If your image files are the *only* things under a specific directory

```
git add <directory>
```

will add everything under that directory

Comment: So you're saying that there is no git command for it ... well I guess I'll need to wrap that myself ...  git add 'git status | grep .png' could work :-)

Comment: Actually it works for a non-flat directory structure

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least not with a Bash shell.

Comment: That's how I tested it. `for i in \`find . -name \*.c\`; do echo " " >> $i; done; git add *.c` added every C file in my repository. bash 4.3.11, git 2.1.3, ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Ermmm..., in case of a flat directory structure

```
git add *.jpg *.gif *.png
```

Or in a nested directory structure, the trick is to stop the shell from expanding the `*` symbol, and let git do it. Because git does it recursively for subdirs too.

```
git add \*.jpg \*.gif \*.png
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: ok it just works without \* see kdopen's answer thanks for the help SzG